# How to add object to jQuery object such that I can retrieve it later?

Tags: jquery

Example of what's happening:

```
> $('#start_date').dateTime = {bacon:5, myFunc: function() { ... }}
Object {bacon: 5, myFunc: function}
> $('#start_date').dateTime
undefined
```

I want to be able to retrieve my "bacon" object if I use the same selector.

I get that `$()` is returning a different object each time -- is there a workaround?

I know I can use `.data`, but the API isn't as nice. I'd have to do `$('#start_date').data('dateTime').myFunc()` instead of `$('#start_date').dateTime.myFunc()`.

Comment: What is wrong with `$('#start_date').data('myFunc')()`?

Comment: as you said, $() is returning a different object so there's no way.
I agree with @Paulpro, the .data syntax is not so bad after all :)

Comment: @Paulpro: It's weird. You don't expect `.data` to return a function. Plus, it's not as clean; I'd like to wrap all my `dateTime` functionality under one object.

Comment: @Mark now that i think it... maybe you want to do a plugin. That works as you expect.

Comment: +1 for the use of bacon in your example

Comment: Alternatively, `$('#start_date').data().dateTime.myFunc()`. And lol about the bacon by Bacon

Comment: "you don't expect `.data` to return a function" - not true, I expect `data` to return *anything*, because it's designed to hold *everything*, which includes functions.

Comment: What's wrong with just doing `var myJQObject = $("#whatever"); myJQObject.dateTime = {/* whatever */};`?

Comment: @11684, you will lose that value if you select that element again. The point is not to cache the jQuery map, the point is to associate data with a DOM element.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Fair point, but I'd like to hear the OP's opinion about this too.

Comment: @11684, OP made it explicit in the question "I want to be able to retrieve my "bacon" object if I use the same selector.".

Comment: @11684: zzzzBov is correct. I'm designing an API; the element can be accessed from anywhere. I don't want to have to carry a global reference to this specific object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you feel slightly better if you do this instead?

`$('#start_date').data().dateTime.myFunc()`

---

**Alternatively, you can extend jQuery to make your life easier, or make jQuery work the way you like**

Here I've whipped up a small plugin tailored for you so that you can pass in a dot-notation string to retrieve the data you want. In this case, it returns a function, so we can directly call it.

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/terryyounghk/8tWLn/

**Plugin code**

```
// Small plugin
$.fn.myData = function (namespace) {
    var namespaces = namespace.split('.'),
        data = this.data();
    $.each(namespaces, function (i, that) {
        data = data[that];
    });
    return data;
}
```

**Usage Example**

```
// set your data
$('#start_date').data('dateTime', {
    bacon:5, 
    myFunc: function() { 
        alert('mmm, bacon') 
    }
});


// call your function, note the dot notation
$('#start_date').myData('dateTime.myFunc')(); // better?
```

The philosophy here is, if we're constantly repeating stuff, there must be something stupid going on. **Is there a way to extend jQuery to make life easier for me?** You be the judge.

Personally, I don't prefer this plugin. I prefer my first suggestion if I am coding one-liners. But who knows? You might like the latter.

Comment: Nah, I like your first solution better. It's the `()()` (function returning a function that's called inline) part that might throw people off. We're PHP devs here, PHP doesn't even support that ;) At least not in 5.3.

Comment: That sounds like an issue with the developers rather than an issue with the code. i don't try to write PHP as though it's JS, why would you try to write JS as though it's PHP?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the property to DOM element, instead of jQuery object:

```
$('#start_date')[0].dateTime = {bacon:5};
console.log($('#start_date')[0].dateTime);
```

Or you can maintain some kind of dictionary with selectors as keys. However, the calling would  still be not very stylish and values are not connected with DOM:

```
//for example save your data by id attribute
DOMData[$('someselector').attr('id')].dateTime = {bacon: 5};
```

Comment: You're extending the native HTMLElement....I thought people advised against this?

Comment: yes, it can cause memory leaks because of circular references, that is why the data api came in in the first place

Comment: @Mark since you don't want to work with `data-` attributes, my guess, that is the only way.

Comment: If we do that, then brace yourselves for the `[0]` and `.get(0)`. I think the OP's intention is to seek an intuitive approach in terms of coding and readability.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery way of associating data with a DOM element is to use the [`data` method](http://api.jquery.com/data):

```
$('#start_date').data('dateTime', {bacon:5, myFunc: function() { ... }});
```

once you've set the data, you can call:

```
baconTime = $('#start_date').data('dateTime');
baconTime.myFunc();
```

As far as the API is concerned, it's consistent with the rest of the jQuery api, where the accessor version is:

```
$(...).method(key);
```

and the mutator version is:

```
$(...).method(key, value);
```

Comment: I guess `data` is the way to go then. Thanks!